# Outlook 2003 add-in - Getting COM exception on application shutdown after creating WPF window

Tags: .net, exception, com, outlook, vsto

I'm developing an outlook 2003 add-in. Until now I used only winforms to display one form, but today I've added a WPF window for more complex stuff. DUe to the WPF window, a COM exception is being thrown when outlook shuts down.

Does anybody know why? I need to start a separate thread for the WPF window in single apartment state.

Here is the exception:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.InvalidComObjectException was unhandled
  Message="COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used."
  Source="PresentationCore"
  StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Input.TextServicesContext.StopTransitoryExtension()
       at System.Windows.Input.TextServicesContext.Uninitialize(Boolean appDomainShutdown)
       at System.Windows.Input.TextServicesContext.TextServicesContextShutDownListener.OnShutDown(Object target)
       at MS.Internal.ShutDownListener.HandleShutDown(Object sender, EventArgs e)
  InnerException:
```

Best Regards,
Oliver Hanappi

Answer (score 2):

You need to Invoke Shutdown on WPF window Dispatcher in the same thread after the window is closed.

```
window.Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown();
```

A similar problem was reported in [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/318333/unit-tests-which-show-windows-cause-vstesthost-mstest-shutdown-crashes-in-vs-2008-rtm)

Comment: NICE.  That worked great for me.  Updating another answer I gave (about starting WPF Window in a new thread) to include this.